# open enquiry form when we hover to close button "X"

Tags: javascript, html, css, php-7.2

when we hover to close button "X", how to open enquiry form?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site - this site is not a free code writing service, this is for people who have attempted some code and got stuck with a problem or error

Comment: yes it can be done. can you please tell what you have tried so far

Comment: when we tryning to close the webpage and hover to that close button then one enquiry form should be open

Comment: 1) We can't read your mind. 2) StackOverflow is NOT here to do work for you, it only helps you with concrete problems. 3) Provide your code, if you have any.

Comment: @AkshayPatil No, that is not possible.

Comment: Use `mouseleave` on `window` https://bradsknutson.com/blog/javascript-detect-mouse-leaving-browser-window/

Comment: @elveti thanks for your solution i will try this. i exactly want this kinda solution

Comment: if anyone can provide example of this please do provide. I am not much experianced guy i am just a beginner

Answer (score 0):

```
function addEvent(obj, evt, fn) {
    if (obj.addEventListener) {
        obj.addEventListener(evt, fn, false);
    }
    else if (obj.attachEvent) {
        obj.attachEvent("on" + evt, fn);
    }
}
addEvent(window,"load",function(e) {
    addEvent(document, "mouseout", function(e) {
        e = e ? e : window.event;
        var from = e.relatedTarget || e.toElement;
        if (!from || from.nodeName == "HTML") {
            // stop your drag event here
            // for now we can just use an alert
            alert("left window");
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: https://unwillingfumblingchord--five-nine.repl.co/

Code: https://repl.it/repls/UnwillingFumblingChord or https://jsfiddle.net/m1Lkj5nt/2/